# preg_match_all to get link, style and script tag in HTML

Tags: preg-match-all

Please help me to solve this problem.

My code is:

```
    preg_match_all('/<(link|style|script)(.*?)(\/>|<\/style>|<\/script>)/i', $tpl_content, $styles);
```

It will not work if link tag end with '>' (only work if link tag end with '/>'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wanted everything between the tags as well, it's in an uncaptured group in this:

```
/(<(?:link|style|script)(?:.*?)(?:\/)?>)(?:(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$))(<\/(?:style|script)>)?/i
```

I would use PREG_SET_ORDER flag in this btw. foreach row, [0] is entire match, [1] is start/all, and [2] is optional end tag

```
$string = '<link lan="hello"/><script language=\'javascript\'>$(document).ready(function() {}</script>'
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/(<(?:link|style|script)(?:.*?)(?:\\/)?>)(?:(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$))(<\\/(?:style|script)>)?/i', $string , $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```